# How do I Log an object's keys and values

Tags: java, android, class, object, spinner

In my Android app, I have a class with the names and phone numbers of the user's contact list. I also have a spinner that lists the contacts' names. When a user selects a name from the spinner, I want to `Log` the contact's name and number.

Here's `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.mycompy.myapp;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    // this class will hold contact names and numbers
    public class ContactInfo {
        public String contactName, phoneNumber;

        public ContactInfo(String contactName, String phoneNumber){
            this.contactName = contactName;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return contactName;
        }
    }

    public Spinner contactSpinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<ContactInfo> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null); // A SQL query for contacts data table, in Java form, I think...
        contactSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        contactSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // If there are contacts, this code goes
        if(cur.getCount()>0){
            while(cur.moveToNext()){
                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)
                );
                String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)
                );

                if(
                    Integer.parseInt(
                            cur.getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)
                            )
                    ) > 0
                ){
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id},null
                    );
                    while(pCur.moveToNext()){
                        String phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
                        );

                        // Add contact's info to `contactList`
                        ContactInfo newContact = new ContactInfo(name,phone);
                        contactList.add(newContact);
                        Log.v("onCreate", String.valueOf(newContact));
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }

        // Add items to spinner
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,contactList);
        contactSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); // Spinner shows contact names only, which is what I want spinner to show
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        Log.v("onItemSelected", String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos))); // When user selects a contact, this Logs just the contact name, but I want contact name AND number
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }

    // Rest of code...
}
```

How do I edit `onItemSelected()` so it `Log`s the selected contact name AND phone number?

Comment: You don't need to show all this Android code when the question is just about logging information from your ContactInfo class.

Answer (score 1):

As the method String.valueOf(Object) calls the toString method from the given object you can just program it to print exactly what you want.

Try something like this

```
public class ContactInfo {
    public String contactName, phoneNumber;

    public ContactInfo(String contactName, String phoneNumber){
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return contactName + " - " + phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add getters for the name and number, otherwise, sooner or later someone is going to try to parse the toString return value to get at the individual pieces. I think Josh Bloch talks about this in *Effective Java*, perhaps in item 10 or item 50.

Comment: @Patrick Right, but I want the spinner to show just the names, while Log shows name and number. With your code, the spinner shows both. Is there a way to have the spinner show just the names, while `Log` shows both?

Comment: @Generic_User_ID You can use a subclass of `Adapter` for the spinner that only uses the name, instead of using the toString() command.

Comment: @Generic_User_ID you can create another method that returns the string as you want to log and keep the toString untouched. Imagine the new method name is toLogString(), then, call `Log.v("OnItemSelected", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toLogString());`